# Check if a string has a particular format?

Tags: java, regex, string, format

I need a `boolean` to check if a given string follows the below format:

**x.x.x** or **1.2.3** , where **x** is a single digit

```
if string format == x.x.x then TRUE.
if string format != x.x.x then FALSE.
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: regex. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: Yes, there are simple Java answers. Look into regex.

Comment: \\d\\.\\d\\.\\d\\. regex will do it..

Comment: i have no idea which i should be using. any suggestions? they all seem to work, there will be a few hundred strings checked.

Comment: Use Christian's / mine "where '.' are escaped . Otherwise it is wrong.

Comment: @ThatGuy343 - You should have given a better sample I/O. From what I can see in your question, x is a number and a number can have multiple digits. But all the answers provided till now consider only a single digit as a number. The answers shouldn't be blamed later for something which wasn't clear from your end.

Comment: It's only a single digit, sorry for not making that clear at first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try using this *regex*:

```
String x = "9.8.7";
boolean matches = x.matches("\\d\\.\\d\\.\\d"); // true
```

Notice that the dot `.` is being *escaped* `\\.`, because it has a special meaning in *regex*.

Here some *input/output* samples:

```
"99.8.7"   -> false
"9.9.7."   -> false
"9.97"     -> false
```

Comment: I can't find any bugs with this method, will mark as answer when SO lets me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex check in Java as follows:

```
String testString = "1.2.3";
boolean isCorrectFormat = testString.matches("\\d\\.\\d\\.\\d");
```

**Sample Tests:**

And some input/output samples:

```
"11.22.33" -> false

"1.2.3."   -> false

"1.23"     -> false

"1.1.1"    -> True
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [String#matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) with regex `\d\.\d\.\d`.

```
  String str="1.2.3";
  boolean isMatch=str.matches("\\d\\.\\d\\.\\d");
```

Comment: @ThatGuy343 it actually doesn't - try `12345` it will also match. You need escape the dot.

Comment: also it matches 1a2b3 or 1,2,3

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yep you're right, didn't catch that.

Answer (score 2):

```
String testString = "1.2.3";
boolean isCorrectFormat = testString.matches("\\d\\.\\d\\.\\d"); \\ You have to escape the "."
```

Comment: Seems like there is an additional right paranthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = "1.2.3";
    boolean hi = x.matches("[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]");
    //or x.matches("\\d{1,10}\\.\\d{1,10}\\.\\d{1,10}");
    //Where 1-> is the minimum digits and 10 is the maximum number of digits before .

    System.out.println(hi);
}
```

Comment: Nope, 1) you haven't. 2) dot matches _everything_ so your pattern matches any 5 character `String` as long as `1`, `3` and `5` are numbers.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Thanks boris.. :)